# i get this error when i try to import {google} from @agm/core/services/google-maps-types

Tags: dictionary, angular8

i get this error when i try to

```
import {google} from @agm/core/services/google-maps-types
```

then got Error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@agm/core/services/google-maps-types'
```

How can i solve this error? please help me.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take some time to review the [tour] and [ask]. Provide any relevant details, add some context, help others help you. Ideally provide a [mcve].